# C# Display table with data from website in Unity (data is from mysql using php)

Tags: c#, php, html, mysql, unity-game-engine

I new here and in programming world.

I need help with show table with data from website in Unity.
This is what website display:

```html
B220053GOS B220 48 OUT FIBER MTO 5 53 155 
B220076GOS B220 48 OUT FIBER MTO 5 76 155 
B220083GOS B220 48 OUT FIBER MTO 5 83 155 
B220104GOS B220 24 OUT FIBER ST 1 104 155 
B220165GOS B220 24 OUT FIBER MTO 5 165 155 
B220171GOS B220 24 OUT FIBER MTO 5 171 155 
B220025BOS B220 48 OUT FIBER MTO 5 25 300 
B220033BOS B220 48 OUT FIBER MTO 5 33 300 
B220040BOS B220 48 OUT FIBER MTO 5 40 300 
B220051BOS B220 48 OUT FIBER MTO 5 51 300 
B220053BOS B220 48 OUT FIBER MTO 5 53 300 
B220060BOS B220 36 OUT FIBER ST 1 60 300 
B220064BOS B220 36 OUT FIBER MTO 5 64 300 
B220076BOS B220 24 OUT FIBER MTO 5 76 300 
B220080BOS B220 24 OUT FIBER ST 1 80 300 
B220083BOS B220 24 OUT FIBER MTO 5 83 300 
B220089BOS B220 24 OUT FIBER MTO 5 89 300 
B220095BOS B220 24 OUT FIBER MTO 5 65 300 
B220102BOS B220 24 OUT FIBER ST 1 102 300 
B220104BOS B220 24 OUT FIBER MTO 5 104 300 
B220106BOS B220 24 OUT FIBER MTO 5 106 300 
B220110BOS B220 24 OUT FIBER ST 1 110 300 
B220114BOS B220 24 OUT FIBER MTO 5 114 300 
B220120BOS B220 12 OUT FIBER MTO 5 120 300 
B220130BOS B220 12 OUT FIBER ST 1 130 300 
B220140BOS B220 12 OUT FIBER MTO 5 140 300 
B220152BOS B220 12 OUT FIBER MTO 5 152 300 
B220156BOS B220 12 OUT FIBER MTO 5 156 300 
B220165BOS B220 12 OUT FIBER ST 1 165 300 
B220167BOS B220 12 OUT FIBER MTO 5 167 300 
B220171BOS B220 12 OUT FIBER MTO 5 171 300 
B220174BOS B220 12 OUT FIBER MTO 5 174 300 
B220184BOS B220 12 OUT FIBER MTO 5 184 300 
B220220BOS B220 12 OUT FIBER MTO 5 220 300 
B220053COS B220 48 OUT FIBER MTO 5 53 360 
B220064COS B220 36 OUT FIBER MTO 5 64 360 
B220076COS B220 36 OUT FIBER MTO 5 76 360 
B220083COS B220 24 OUT FIBER MTO 5 83 360 
B220110COS B220 24 OUT FIBER MTO 5 110 360 
B220071OOS B220 24 OUT FIBER MTO 5 71 400 
B220083OOS B220 24 OUT FIBER MTO 5 83 400 
B220110OOS B220 24 OUT FIBER MTO 5 110 400 
B220025EOS B220 48 OUT FIBER MTO 5 25 450 
B220033EOS B220 48 OUT FIBER MTO 5 33 450 
B220040EOS B220 36 OUT FIBER ST 1 40 450 
B220044EOS B220 36 OUT FIBER MTO 5 44 450 
B220050EOS B220 48 OUT FIBER MTO 5 50 450 
B220051EOS B220 48 OUT FIBER MTO 5 51 450 
B220053EOS B220 48 OUT FIBER MTO 5 53 450 
B220060EOS B220 36 OUT FIBER ST 1 60 450 
B220064EOS B220 36 OUT FIBER ST 1 64 450 
B220071EOS B220 36 OUT FIBER MTO 5 71 450 
B220076EOS B220 24 OUT FIBER MTO 5 76 450 
B220080EOS B220 24 OUT FIBER ST 1 80 450 
B220083EOS B220 24 OUT FIBER ST 1 83 450 
B220089EOS B220 24 OUT FIBER MTO 5 89 450 
B220090EOS B220 24 OUT FIBER ST 1 90 450 
B220095EOS B220 24 OUT FIBER MTO 5 95 450 
B220102EOS B220 24 OUT FIBER ST 1 102 450 
B220104EOS B220 24 OUT FIBER MTO 5 104 450 
B220106EOS B220 24 OUT FIBER MTO 5 106 450 
B220110EOS B220 24 OUT FIBER ST 1 110 450 
B220114EOS B220 24 OUT FIBER MTO 5 114 450 
B220120EOS B220 12 OUT FIBER MTO 5 120 450 
B220130EOS B220 12 OUT FIBER ST 1 130 450 
B220140EOS B220 12 OUT FIBER MTO 5 140 450 
B220152EOS B220 12 OUT FIBER ST 1 152 450 
B220154EOS B220 12 OUT FIBER MTO 5 154 450 
B220156EOS B220 12 OUT FIBER MTO 5 156 450 
B220165EOS B220 12 OUT FIBER ST 1 165 450 
B220171EOS B220 12 OUT FIBER MTO 5 171 450 
B220172EOS B220 12 OUT FIBER MTO 5 172 450 
B220174EOS B220 12 OUT FIBER MTO 5 174 450 
B220178EOS B220 12 OUT FIBER MTO 5 178 450 
B220180EOS B220 12 OUT FIBER ST 1 180 450 
B220184EOS B220 12 OUT FIBER MTO 5 184 450 
B220191EOS B220 12 OUT FIBER MTO 5 191 450 
B220203EOS B220 12 OUT FIBER MTO 5 203 450 
B220216EOS B220 12 OUT FIBER MTO 5 216 450 
B220220EOS B220 12 OUT FIBER ST 1 220 450 
B220051FOS B220 48 OUT FIBER MTO 5 51 500 
B220064FOS B220 36 OUT FIBER MTO 5 64 500 
B220076FOS B220 24 OUT FIBER MTO 5 76 500 
B220080FOS B220 24 OUT FIBER MTO 5 80 500 
B220089FOS B220 24 OUT FIBER MTO 5 89 500 
B220102FOS B220 24 OUT FIBER MTO 5 102 500 
B220108FOS B220 24 OUT FIBER MTO 5 108 500 
B220114FOS B220 24 OUT FIBER MTO 5 114 500 
B220127FOS B220 12 OUT FIBER MTO 5 127 500 
B220055TOM B220 12 OUT PLASTIC ST 1 55 600 
B220064TOS B220 24 OUT FIBER MTO 5 64 600 
B220080TOM B220 12 OUT PLASTIC ST 1 80 600 
B220095TOS B220 12 OUT FIBER MTO 5 95 600 
B2220106TOS B220 12 OUT FIBER MTO 5 106 600 
B220110TOM B220 12 OUT PLASTIC ST 1 110 600 
B220110TOS B220 12 OUT FIBER MTO 5 110 600 
B220120TOS B220 12 OUT FIBER MTO 5 120 600 
B220152TOS B220 12 OUT FIBER MTO 5 152 600 
B220165TOS B220 12 OUT FIBER MTO 5 165 600 
B220095WOS B220 12 OUT FIBER MTO 5 95 625 
B220110WOS B220 12 OUT FIBER ST 1 110 625 
B220130WOS B220 12 OUT FIBER MTO 5 130 625 
B220152WOS B220 12 OUT FIBER MTO 5 152 625 
B220165WOS B220 12 OUT FIBER MTO 5 165 625 
B220220WOS B220 12 OUT FIBER MTO 5 220 625 
B220040ZOS B220 24 OUT FIBER MTO 5 40 900 
B220051ZOS B220 24 OUT FIBER MTO 5 51 900 
B220060ZOS B220 12 OUT FIBER MTO 5 60 900 
B220064ZOS B220 12 OUT FIBER MTO 5 64 900 
B220076ZOS B220 12 OUT FIBER MTO 5 76 900 
B220080ZOS B220 12 OUT FIBER MTO 5 80 900 
B220083ZOS B220 12 OUT FIBER MTO 5 83 900 
B220095ZOS B220 12 OUT FIBER MTO 5 95 900 
B220102ZOS B220 6 OUT FIBER MTO 5 102 900 
B220106ZOS B220 6 OUT FIBER MTO 5 106 900 
B220110ZOS B220 6 OUT FIBER ST 1 110 900 
B220130ZOS B220 6 OUT FIBER MTO 5 130 900 
B220131ZOS B220 6 OUT FIBER MTO 5 131 900 
B220140ZOS B220 6 OUT FIBER MTO 5 140 900 
B220152ZOS B220 6 OUT FIBER MTO 5 152 900 
B220154ZOS B220 6 OUT FIBER ST 1 154 900 
B220160ZOS B220 6 OUT FIBER MTO 5 160 900 
B220165ZOS B220 6 OUT FIBER MTO 5 165 900 
B220171ZOS B220 6 OUT FIBER MTO 5 171 900 
B220174ZOS B220 6 OUT FIBER MTO 5 174 900 
B220178ZOS B220 6 OUT FIBER MTO 5 178 900 
B220083MOS B220 12 OUT FIBER MTO 5 83 1000 
B220089MOS B220 12 OUT FIBER MTO 5 89 1000 
B220106MOS B220 12 OUT FIBER MTO 5 106 1000
```

I need this in the table showing in the Unity UI:

```html
Number        Type    In Case    Ink ...   and etc.
B220053GOS    B220    48         OUT
```

then after every column button "Request Order", this button gets all data from column for example:

```html
Number      Type      etc...
B220053GOS  B220
```

and send in the email :)

Comment: Not sure why the php and mysql tags are necessary here. Sounds like you are pulling data from a website to display in Unity3D. It might help if you explained to us where you are displaying the data, the Unity UI doesn't have tables built in, so you'll need to do a fair bit of work to get this data displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You should elaborate what you mean "display". I assume you want to parse this data to dictionary? Best way might be to export your data to CSV (Comma separated value) file and use this:

http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=CSVReader

If you wish just to display data in the console use 
DebugOutputGrid() method